# Peculiar behavior on the far right side of <body>

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to implement a custom context menu and this means I have to take care of the edges of the container (so that the menu doesn't appear outside of visible boundaries).

So far, my simple proof-of-concept works but there's some weird interaction between the conditionals for checking if the menu will be outside the bottom edge and outside the right edge.

```
 if((context.clientHeight + e.pageY) > (body.clientHeight)){
    context.style.top = (e.pageY - context.clientHeight) + "px";
 }

 if((context.clientWidth + e.pageX) > (body.clientWidth)){
    context.style.left = (e.pageX - context.clientWidth) + "px";
 }
```

Alone, each of these conditionals produces exactly the intended behavior, except the one that checks for the right boundary somehow is off by about 16 pixels, which I can't explain. The really weird part however is that when I leave both conditionals there, on the far right and bottom corner there is a square area that will cause the context menu to always appear outside it, regardless of the click's distance to the edge. It's as if with both conditions, the menu refuses to appear within that square, even though it is happy to do so with only one of the two conditions.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z0fys5n6/1/). I'm stumped by this since the occasional console logging of coordinates seems to produce the expected numbers.

Comment: Making the problematic dimension definite (specifying it in the CSS) seems to eliminate the problem. I'm still interested in why this behavior appears however and why the interaction between the rules is important to it, since it doesn't happen when only the non-specified dimension's condition is active alone.

Comment: @humble.rumble I _did_ provide a fiddle, it's been in the OP all along. offsetHeight/Width vs their client counterparts should indeed make no difference, especially in this implementation. However, that would still not explain why each condition works perfectly well alone, but their combination causes weird behavior.

Comment: @humble.rumble Firefox Developer Edition (40.0a2). Did you try the lower right corner?

Comment: @humble.rumble np, the fixed dimensions solve it for my current project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that is related to your problem in FireFox yet in Chrome you encounter two problems:

One is the textflow with makes your conditions wrong, since the context.clientWidth changes (from 52 to 40) if you reach the right edge due to text and padding breaks.
Therefore add:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

to .menu-item{}

Also you are going to encounter problems when facing scrollbars. In my experience it is better to just change side instead of the far right corner from the middle of the page.
I forked you an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ncstjbyq/

Comment: The why is simple. Since you caluclate with clientWidth and clientHeight. This messed up your height and width calculations since the element gets more narrow and more high than initially.This is why it starts jumping the more you get to the bottom right border. The higher the element is the more you reduce of it (e.pageX - context.clientHeight) so the more it jumps. Same goes for the width, the narrower it gets the less you reduced from it, so it gets outside of the border.

Comment: This only makes sense to me if the menu's dimensions are changing before it is updated on the screen. Is that what's happening? Because otherwise, it appears to just have the same dimensions it used to (the menu) which is why I didn't suspect this as the cause.

Comment: The menu has an initial width of 52px. Now depending on the position it narrows down to 40, increasing the height therefore. With those new dimensions you are calculation the new position. After those calculations the left is smaller again (due to left - clientWidth of 40px) and thereby the menu goes back to its initial dimension again. It stops breaking and goes back to 52px - thus overlapping your border.